# Phonegap Android force numeric keyboard on input

Tags: android, cordova, input, keyboard, numbers

I'm using

```
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

on my input fields in my app to prevent several behavior with android ICS but i would like to force the numeric keyboard to show up on specific inputs. And i want to keep the CSS line.

Is there a way to do it ? by modifying some classes in the .java files ? Or maybe is there another way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On HTML5 (as you're talking on Java mods, I wrote this to be clear):

The only way to trigger the numeric keyboard on Android devices is to use `<input type="number">` or `<input type="tel">`. That comes with some small problems, especially if you're dealing with Angular or with HTML5 native validation, but for the general use this should be no problem.